# Average of angles

Tags: geometry, average, pi, angle

For example, when calculating an average of angle $\pi$ and $-\pi$,
just adding them up and divide with 2 is 0, but since they are the same *angle*, shouldn't it be $\pi$ or $-\pi$? (180 deg)

Do I *always* have to use [this fomula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities#Mean_of_angles) when adding, subtracting, averaging an angle?

Guys, why everyone is commenting about the equality of plus and minus?

Using the average method in the link, the average of *angle* $\pi$ and $-\pi$ is $\pi$!

I want to know what is a correct way of adding, subtracting, averaging an ***angle***

Comment: They aren't same angle. Are $-1$ and $1$ same?

Comment: They are not the same angles. Is $\sin\pi/2=\sin-\pi/2$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri The last time I tried to check the equality...it worked =-1

Comment: Whoops....lol....

Comment: I don't understand the first 2 comments. Why 1 and $\pi/2$ came out? I said about $\pi$...

Comment: $-2$ and $2$ are distinct points lying on opposite sides of $0$ on the number line. $-\pi$ and $\pi$ are angles opening clockwise and anticlockwise from positive x-axis.

Comment: @cosmo5 But isn't angle scalar?

Comment: Yes angles are scalar. But they have a sense of rotation (this is not direction). Just like numbers have sense, negative numbers go to $- \infty$, positive numbers go to $+ \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of angles as representing travel around the unit circle, starting at $(1,0)$ on the $x$-axis. Then $\pi$ is a counterclockwise rotation half way around and $-\pi$ is a clockwise rotation by the same amount. In this sense they do in fact average to $0$, even though both rotations end at the same point $(-1,0)$.

**Edit** in response to comment.

The formula in the link calculates (in one sense) the average of the final positions of the rotations corresponding to two angles.

Whether you want the "average angle" to mean
"average amount of rotation" or "average final position" depends on how you plan to use the average in an application. The link points out that on a clock, so for things like time of day, you want the average of the final position.

So the answer to this part of the question:

> Do I *always* have to use this formula when adding, subtracting, averaging an angle?

is no. You use this method *sometimes*.

Comment: Can you explain more? Then how can I express the average of the two angles? (-1, 0) or $0$?

Comment: @김선달 see my edit.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have to treat *angle* and *angle final position* as a different thing. And if I'm only interested in the *position*, I have to only use the link method. Did I get it right?

Comment: @김선달 I think you have it right. Just make sure you get sensible answers in your application.